# iOS UI Test Does Not Recognize Items in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

I am writing a demo app where I store items in NSUserDefaults. The iOS UI Test looks like this:

```
 func test_should_create_account_successfully() {

        app.textFields["usernameTextField"].tapAndType(text: "johndoe")
        app.textFields["passwordTextField"].tapAndType(text: "password")

        app.buttons["registerButton"].tap()

        let users = dataAccess.getUsers()
        XCTAssertTrue(users.count > 0)
    }
```

The registerButton tap fired the following code:

```
 @IBAction func saveButtonClicked() {

    let user = User(username: self.usernameTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!)
    self.dataAccess.saveUser(user)
}
```

DataAccess class is defined below:

```
  func saveUser(_ user:User)  {

        user.userId = UUID().uuidString

        var users = getUsers()
        users.append(user)

        let usersData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: users)

        // save the user
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.setValue(usersData, forKey: "users")
        userDefaults.synchronize()

    }

    func getUsers() -> [User] {

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let usersData = userDefaults.value(forKey: "users") as? Data
        if usersData == nil {
            return [User]()
        }

        let users = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: usersData!) as! [User]
        return users
    }
```

The problem is that the following line always return 0 users:

```
let users = dataAccess.getUsers()
```

This only happens in iOS UI Test and not in normal Unit Test target.

UPDATE: User class is NSCoding Protocol compatible

```
public class User : NSObject, NSCoding {

    var username :String!
    var password :String!
    var userId :String!

    init(username :String, password :String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(self.userId,forKey: "userId")
        aCoder.encode(self.username, forKey: "username")
        aCoder.encode(self.password, forKey: "password")
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        self.userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as! String
        self.username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as! String
        self.password = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as! String
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your class User is not properly encoded do it like this sample class (in swift 3):

```
class User: NSObject, NSCoding  {
    let name : String
    let url : String
    let desc : String

    init(tuple : (String,String,String)){
        self.name = tuple.0
        self.url = tuple.1
        self.desc = tuple.2
    }
    func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
    func getURL() -> String{
        return url
    }
    func getDescription() -> String {
        return desc
    }
    func getTuple() -> (String, String, String) {
        return (self.name,self.url,self.desc)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.url = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "url") as? String ?? ""
        self.desc = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "desc") as? String ?? ""
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(self.url, forKey: "url")
        aCoder.encode(self.desc, forKey: "desc")
    }
}
```

then save and get it from UserDefaults like this:

```
func save() {
    let data  = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey:"userData" )
}

func get() -> MyObject? {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userData") as? Data else { return nil }
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? MyObject
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and that was not the issue. It is encoded fine because when I use Unit Test project (not iOS UI Test Project) then it is persisted fine.

Comment: try printing all key value pairs of Userdefauls for debugging purpose

Comment: I think it is more of a problem of  different targets when accessing NSUserDefaults. The weird part is that a normal iOS Unit Test project works.